# What is streamTimeout() and sessionTimeout() in RSocket Resume()

Tags: rsocket

What is the difference in setreamTimeout and sessionDuration in RSocket Resume()? How/when to use it?

```
Resume resume =
                new Resume()
                        .streamTimeout(vv)
                        .sessionDuration(vv)
```